# How can I return elements that have no, empty, or whitespace ids?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am reconfiguring a complicated HTML document with 100+ input elements. I'd like to quickly find any elements that either have a blank id (`<input type="text" name="something" id="" ...`), an id with only whitespace (`<button name="unimportant" id=" "...`), or no idea at all (`<select name="whatever">` so that I can make the necessary corrections to the source.

I know that the selector for blank id would be `$('[id=""]')`, but how can I get all the target elements with one selector (or concatenated selectors)?

Example HTML:

```
<form id="provision">
  <input type="text" name="something" id="" value="blank id" /><br />
  <input type="text" name="something2" value="no id" /><br />
  <select name="something3"><option>No id</option></select><br />
  <textarea name="something4" id="">Blank id</textarea><br />
  <button name="something5" id=" ">whitespace id</button><br />
  <button name="something6" id="  ">extra whitespace id</button><br />
  <label><input type="radio" name="something7" id="
">Carriage return id</label>
</form>
```

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/VNdL6/ for an example that adds red borders (`.css('border-color', 'red')`).

Comment: The white-space-only IDs are invalid--the HTML is malformed--so strictly speaking you can't expect anything to work reliably; for instance, the behavior of `document.getElementById` or even querySelector (which I assume jQuery uses if available) is inpredictable. Why don't you fix whatever is creating the broken ID's, or preprocess the broken HTML to eliminate the invalid IDs; then you can simply search using `document.querySelectorAll('input:not([id])')`.

Comment: @torazaburo: I might just do that. I'm looking for a way to to quickly identify the problematic elements so I can fix the underlying problems in the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter out element with blank ids or ids consists of spaces. You can apply the complex filters according to your need in filter function.

```
$(':input').filter(function(){
     if($.trim(this.id).length == 0)
           return $(this);
}).css('border-color', 'red')
```

Comment: Here, you can borrow my `{}` since you seem to have run out :)

Comment: You're missing braces around your `if` block.

Comment: Hmmm, works for everything but ids that include [carriage return]. http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/VNdL6/12/

Comment: I think braces are not required here as I have only one statement under if.

Comment: Please forgive; this *does* work for carriage return (I was trying to apply a border color to a `type="radio"`. See http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/VNdL6/16/.

Answer (score 3):

Separate selectors with comma:

```
$("[id=''], [id=' '], :not([id])").css("border-color", "red");
```

Another option is to use filtering:

```
$("[id]").filter(function() {
    return $.trim(this.id) === "";
}).add(":not([id])").css("border-color", "red");
```

Comment: and `,:not([id])` for those that don't have an id at all.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, I forgot about *with no `id`*.

Comment: +1 for getting mostly there. First option doesn't catch id with whitespace of more than one space (or carriage returns): http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/VNdL6/13/, nor does second option: http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/VNdL6/14/. When I try to apply `.trim` (`return this.id.trim === ""` ;http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/VNdL6/15/) I actually get farther away!

Comment: @JeromyFrench Then the last option is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, excellent. This option also highlights non-input elements (like `<div id="">`), which could be useful (see http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/VNdL6/21/). Thank you for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid potential problems with invalid IDs, and resulting unpredictable behavior from `querySelector` or its jQuery equivalent, which could affect @VisioN's solution, I might try something like

```
[].concat(document.getElementsByTagName("input")).forEach(function(elt){
    if(elt.hasAttribute("id") && /^\s*$/.test(elt.getAttribute("id")) {
        elt.removeAttribute("id");
    }
});
```

or the equivalent if you are not in an ECMAScript5 environment.

This is roughly equivalent to what @Adil is doing, although it removes the invalid IDs instead of just setting the border color property on them.

Then the coloring can be done with a CSS rule

```
input:not([id]) { border-color: red; }
```